# edit .htaccess file for custom error web page - not working

Tags: server, apache2, php

I am trying to make a custom error page by editing the `.htaccess` file. But after editing and saving the file `.htaccess`, I do not get my custom error page. Instead I get the standard error message

> Not found
>   The requested URL /hello.html was not found on this server

I am using Apache2 server.

```
ErrorDocument 404 "<H1>Page not found</H1>"
```

Comment: For how to do a custom not found page see the [Ubuntu Serverguide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html) - default settings - 2.

Comment: Do you configure Allow override? .htaccess don't work whiout this configuration